# deploying xml policy to apim using bicep

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management, azure-bicep

I'd like to deploy the following policy to azure api management:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
    <base />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(!context.Variables.ContainsKey(''cachedAccessToken'') || DateTime.UtcNow >= (DateTime)context.Variables[''tokenExpiry''])">
            <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="{0}" />
            <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="tokenResponse" timeout="20" ignore-error="false">
                <set-url>{1}/token</set-url>
                <set-method>POST</set-method>
                <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                    <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
                </set-header>
                <set-body>@("grant_type=password&username={2}&password=thisShouldRefThe-AmxPassword-NamedValue")</set-body>
            </send-request>
            <set-variable name="tokenResponseJson" value="@{{ return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject((string)context.Variables[''tokenResponse''].Body.As<string>()); }}" />
            <set-variable name="cachedAccessToken" value="@{{(string)context.Variables[''tokenResponseJson''][''access_token'']}}" />
            <set-variable name="tokenExpiry" value="@{{ return DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds((int)context.Variables[''tokenResponseJson''][''expires_in''] - 60); }}" />
            <cache-store-value key="cachedAccessToken" value="@{{context.Variables[''cachedAccessToken'']}}" duration="@{{(new TimeSpan(0, (int)context.Variables[''tokenResponseJson''][''expires_in''], 0))}}" />
            <cache-store-value key="tokenExpiry" value="@{{context.Variables[''tokenExpiry'']}}" duration="@{{(new TimeSpan(0, (int)context.Variables[''tokenResponseJson''][''expires_in''], 0))}}" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <cache-lookup-value key="cachedAccessToken" variable-name="cachedAccessToken" />
            <cache-lookup-value key="tokenExpiry" variable-name="tokenExpiry" />
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
    <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
        <value>@{{$"Bearer {{context.Variables[''cachedAccessToken'']}}"}}</value>
    </set-header>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

This is the bicep that gets run by a devops pipeline:

```
resource apim 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2022-04-01-preview' existing = {
    name: apimName

    resource apiVersionSet 'api-version-sets@2018-06-01-preview' = if (enableApiVersioning) {
        name: apiName
        properties: {
            displayName: displayName
            versioningScheme: versionScheme
            versionHeaderName: 'X-Api-Version'
            versionQueryName: 'api-version'
        }
    }

    resource api 'apis' = {
        name: enableApiVersioning ? apiNameVersioned : apiName
        properties: {
            displayName: displayName
            path: '${pathPrefix}${apiName}'
            format: definitionFormat
            protocols: [
                'https'
            ]
            subscriptionRequired: true
            value: definition
            apiVersion: enableApiVersioning ? version : null
            apiVersionSetId: enableApiVersioning ? apiVersionSet.id : null
            subscriptionKeyParameterNames: {
                header: 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'
                query: 'subscription-key'
            }
        }

        resource apiPolicy 'policies' = if (!empty(policy)) {
            name: 'policy'
            properties: {
                value: policy
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> '=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 13, position 58.

Comment: Can you confirm it is working without the policy ?

Comment: Hi Thomas, yes it works ok when the bicep deploys a simple policy that just sets the backend id

Comment: Did you try the policy without bicep? I'm getting errors. Named values can not be created dynamically. This is not supported `<value>@{{$"Bearer {{context.Variables[''cachedAccessToken'']}}"}}</value>`. Error: `Error in element 'set-header' on line 28, column 6: Expression must be enclosed in parenthesis.`

Comment: @RobBowman if you could try to deploy just the policy on its own so we can try to narrow down the issue. also for the policy you probably wanna specify the format as well: `xml` or `raw-xml` not sure which one should work in your case

Comment: @Thomas sorry for the delay, had a  public holiday for King Charlie on Monday then other work yesterday. Hoping to re-visit this one today

Answer (score 2):

Lesson learned - pay more attention to what chatgpt pumps out!

The main problem was the syntax for the C# code block. Here's the working policy:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
    <base />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(!context.Variables.ContainsKey("cachedAccessToken") || DateTime.UtcNow >= (DateTime)context.Variables["tokenExpiry"])">
            <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="func-amx-api-dev-001" />
            <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="tokenResponse" timeout="20" ignore-error="false">
                <set-url>{{baseurl}}.azurewebsites.net/token</set-url>
                <set-method>POST</set-method>
                <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                    <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
                </set-header>
                <set-body>@("grant_type=password&username={{user}}&password={{AmxPassword}}")</set-body>
            </send-request>
            <set-variable name="cachedAccessToken" value="@((String)((IResponse)context.Variables["jwt"]).Body.As<JObject>()["access_token"])" />
            <set-variable name="tokenExpiry" value="@((String)((IResponse)context.Variables["jwt"]).Body.As<JObject>()["expires_in"])" />
            <cache-store-value key="cachedAccessToken" value="@((String)context.Variables["cachedAccessToken"])" duration="3600" caching-type="internal" />
            <cache-store-value key="tokenExpiry" value="@((String)context.Variables["tokenExpiry"])" duration="3600" caching-type="internal" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <cache-lookup-value key="cachedAccessToken" variable-name="cachedAccessToken" />
            <cache-lookup-value key="tokenExpiry" variable-name="tokenExpiry" />
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
    <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
        <value>@{
                return $"Bearer {(String)context.Variables["cachedAccessToken"]}";
            }</value>
    </set-header>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

I also moved the policy to a separate file and deployed at apim operation level with the following bicep:

```
resource apiPolicy 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/operations/policies@2022-09-01-preview' = {
    name: '${apimName}/amxapi_v1_0_0/entity/policy'
    properties: {
        value: loadTextContent('./createEntityPolicy.xml')
    }
}
```